# JAVA_HOME is pointing to JDK but still got an error when try to build a maven project using jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, configuration, path, java-home

i tried everything and the environmental variable point to jdk 
and the path as well

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241

and still got 
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Comment: What do you see when running "echo %JAVA_HOME%" from command prompt

Comment: try with '/' instead of '\'

Comment: What did you try on "everything"? That would make others helping you. Or you question may be closed.